# Get the FIRST_VALUE from the current partition since stage has changed

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, data-warehouse

I want to use the FIRST_VALUE() function in order to have the first "updated_at" value. But what I want is to have the first value since the stage has changed.

```
with values as (

    select 1 as deal, 2 as stage, '2020-11-10' as updated_at, '2020-11-10' as first_updated_at
    union all
    select 1 as deal, 2 as stage, '2020-11-11' as updated_at, '2020-11-10' as first_updated_at 
    union all
    select 1 as deal, 3 as stage, '2020-11-12' as updated_at, '2020-11-12' as first_updated_at
    union all 
    select 1 as deal, 4 as stage, '2020-11-13' as updated_at, '2020-11-13' as first_updated_at
    union all 
    select 1 as deal, 4 as stage, '2020-11-14' as updated_at, '2020-11-13' as first_updated_at
    union all 
    select 1 as deal, 2 as stage, '2020-11-15' as updated_at, '2020-11-15' as first_updated_at
    union all 
    select 1 as deal, 2 as stage, '2020-11-16' as updated_at, '2020-11-15' as first_updated_at

)
select * from values
```

I am trying to use the FIRST VALUE function like this:

`FIRST_VALUE(updated_at) OVER(PARTITION BY deal, stageORDER BY updated_at ASC`

Am I missing something here or what I want is not possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: . . I assume the last column is desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using window functions.  First, look at the previous stage to see if it is *different* from the previous row.  Then use a cumulative max to take the `updated_at` when this occurs:

```
with values as (

    select 1 as deal, 2 as stage, '2020-11-10' as updated_at, '2020-11-10' as first_updated_at
    union all
    select 1 as deal, 2 as stage, '2020-11-11' as updated_at, '2020-11-10' as first_updated_at 
    union all
    select 1 as deal, 3 as stage, '2020-11-12' as updated_at, '2020-11-12' as first_updated_at
    union all 
    select 1 as deal, 4 as stage, '2020-11-13' as updated_at, '2020-11-13' as first_updated_at
    union all 
    select 1 as deal, 4 as stage, '2020-11-14' as updated_at, '2020-11-13' as first_updated_at
    union all 
    select 1 as deal, 2 as stage, '2020-11-15' as updated_at, '2020-11-15' as first_updated_at
    union all 
    select 1 as deal, 2 as stage, '2020-11-16' as updated_at, '2020-11-15' as first_updated_at

)
select v.*,
       max(case when stage <> prev_stage or prev_stage is null then updated_at end) over (partition by deal order by updated_at) as imputed_first_updated_at
from (select v.*,
             lag(stage) over (partition by deal order by updated_at) as prev_stage
      from values v
     ) v
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to use the FIRST VALUE function ...

Consider below option

```
select * except(updated_at_on_change), 
  ifnull(updated_at_on_change, first_value(updated_at ignore nulls) over win) as first_updated_at
from (
  select *,
    if(stage != ifnull(lag(stage) over win, stage - 1), updated_at, null) updated_at_on_change
  from values
  window win as (partition by deal order by updated_at)
)
window win as (partition by deal order by updated_at desc rows between 1 following and unbounded following )
# order by updated_at
```

If applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]